# How to get Joomla 2.5 and 3.x default/assigned template ID in frontend?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

There are few ways to pull template params from frontend but none of them contain actual template ID ,

I printed the JFactory template object 
http://prntscr.com/1dpewc

```
print_r($app->getTemplate('template'));
```

and just want to make sure that this is the right and the only way to get the template id  in template index.php file.

```
$app            = JFactory::getApplication();
$getTemplateId  = $app->getTemplate('template')->id;
```

everything else fails , $this->id , $app->getTemplate()->id , etc.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where in the front-end? in a template index.php or a view or component controller? and why do you need the template id, it can change if the user uninstalls and re-installs the same template e.g. if they're updating it...

Comment: Yes frontend. I am not chasing after specific ID , I just need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, theres a nomenclature problem here.

The code you have:

```php
$app            = JFactory::getApplication();
$getTemplateId  = $app->getTemplate('template')->id;
```

— is actually giving you the *template style* `id`. (*And yes this is the quickest way to get this.*)

As Riccardo points out the template ID is actually only in the Extensions Managers table (`#__extensions`).

Given your application though (i.e. using it to create a unique Javascript cookie), the template style id is probably what you want as it's more specific that the template ID which you will need to hit the database to retrieve.

Alternatively if you the just want an identifier for the template, you could use:

```
$getTemplateName  = $app->getTemplate('template')->template;
```

Which will give you the templates base name (e.g. `beez_20`) which is unique as it's also the directory name the template is stored in.

Comment: Thank you , looking at all options we all found the right way but the question is which one is faster and accurate. $app->getTemplate('template')->template; will give the template name but the issue is if user is using same template with different style for different page ( assign template ) so I will endup having same names there. Thus I must obtain the ID. But thank you both for the help. Seems like they left that one out for no reason. If you quire modules the same way you do get the module ID but templates this is all I found.

Answer (score 1):

This will select the template style Id:

```
$db->setQuery( 'SELECT id,template FROM #__template_styles WHERE client_id=0 AND home=1');
```

where template will be the unique name of the template, say you assign $tname to it:

Now with this you will select the actual template to get its id:

```
SELECT id FROM #__extensions where `type`='template' and `element`= '$tname'
```

Please quench our curiosity and tell us why you want the template id.

Comment: Thank you but I am trying to avoid unnecessary sql calls. Joomla is packed with classes that should do this. If you just look in backend template ID is there.  I need ti to create unique javascript cookie ( needed for few scripts ) based on active template and this way avoid duplicated cookie on separate installs or assigned templates

Comment: Yes, Joomla classes most likely will help you. But they are still going to query the database, and gather much more data than you need, so their queries will be slower.